# bash yes no function

Tags: bash, function, prompt

I have many Yes/No answers in my script.
How can I create a function to minimize the size of my script?

I have the following:

```
function ask {
    read -n 1 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
            return 1;
    else
            exit
            echo "Abort.."
    fi
}

ask "Continue? [y/N] "
```

It works fine. But the Question "Continue? [y/N] is not displayed. How can I "transfer" this text to my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $1 variable:

```
function ask {
    echo $1        # add this line
    read -n 1 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
            return 1;
    else
            exit
            echo "Abort.."
    fi
}
```

**Edit:** as noted by @cdarke, 'echo' call can be avoided thanks to '-p' switch in read:

```
# echo $1
# read -n 1 -r
read -n 1 -r -p "$1"
```

Comment: You don't need the echo, `read` in Bash has a `-p` option to give a prompt.  `read` can also prompt in ksh, but the syntax is `var?prompt`.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, but it also conflicts with the ksh/zsh coproc read option which is why I typically recommend against it. `-p` in Bash has some advantages if used in combination with `-e`, otherwise it's equivalent to `printf %s 'prompt' >&2` which I'd say is better otherwise.

Comment: At the very least, you need to switch the order of `exit` and `echo "Abort.."`, since right now you won't reach the `echo` statement. Also, consider whether you really want to exit, or merely `return 0`. Also, in shell parlance, `return 1` indicates failure of some kind, not true as in most programming languages, so you probably want to change it so that you return 0 when `$REPLY` is yes, and return 1 otherwise.

Comment: @omaaj: I gave up trying to be portable between shells ages ago, they differ in detail too much.  I prefer to use the features that a shell is good at rather than the lowest common denominator.  I see little merit in trying to write generic scripts unless you have a platform that only supports one shell.  Android might be an example of that, using MKSH (and ignoring SL4A).